# Install xgboost using conda on Debian

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, xgboost

When I try to install conda with following command `conda install -c aterrel xgboost=0.4.0`, I have an error

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - python 3.5*
  - xgboost 0.4.0*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

The command `conda info xbgoost` gives me

```
NoPackagesFoundError: Package missing in current linux-64 channels: 
  - xgboost
```

Ho to fix it and install xgboost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with Anaconda 4.4.0 just type `conda install py-xgboost`

Answer (score 1):

As of conda 4.3.5, there is no option to specify channel to `conda info`. So to print the info of the package, you can do:

```
(root) ~/condaexpts $ conda config --add channels aterrel                                                                                                                                             
(root) ~/condaexpts $ conda info xgboost                                                                                                                                                              
Fetching package metadata ...........

xgboost 0.4.0.c4fa2f py27_0
---------------------------
file name   : xgboost-0.4.0.c4fa2f-py27_0.tar.bz2
name        : xgboost
version     : 0.4.0.c4fa2f
build string: py27_0
build number: 0
channel     : aterrel
size        : 441 KB
arch        : x86_64
license     : ALv2
md5         : 8f282fc35e18ef443771617459eeb8ad
platform    : linux
requires    : ()
subdir      : linux-64
url         : https://conda.anaconda.org/aterrel/linux-64/xgboost-0.4.0.c4fa2f-py27_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    numpy
    python 2.7*
    scikit-learn
    scipy

xgboost 0.4.0 np19py27_0
------------------------
file name   : xgboost-0.4.0-np19py27_0.tar.bz2
name        : xgboost
version     : 0.4.0
build string: np19py27_0
build number: 0
channel     : aterrel
size        : 270 KB
arch        : x86_64
license     : ALv2
md5         : 8dd98afb385109adb42f08337842cc18
platform    : linux
requires    : ()
subdir      : linux-64
url         : https://conda.anaconda.org/aterrel/linux-64/xgboost-0.4.0-np19py27_0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    numpy 1.9*
    python 2.7*
    scikit-learn
    scipy           

(root) ~/condaexpts $ conda config --remove channels aterrel
```

You can also view the same information at the channel's [manifest](https://conda.anaconda.org/aterrel/linux-64/repodata.json).

Coming back to your original query, there is a conflict arising because the package `xgboost` in [aterrel's channel](https://conda.anaconda.org/aterrel/linux-64) has only been built for `python 2.7` and not for `python 3.5` which is also evident by the build string `py27` in the package name.

You can, however, build it for `python 3.5`:

```
(root) ~/condaexpts $ wget https://anaconda.org/aterrel/xgboost/0.4.0.c4fa2f/download/linux-64/xgboost-0.4.0.c4fa2f-py27_0.tar.bz2 
(root) ~/condaexpts $ tar -xf xgboost-0.4.0.c4fa2f-py27_0.tar.bz2 -C /tmp/xgboost/
(root) ~/condaexpts $ conda install conda-build -y
(root) ~/condaexpts $ conda-build /tmp/xgboost/info/recipe
(root) ~/condaexpts $ conda install xgboost --use-local -y
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /home/ubuntu/condaexpts/m3:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    xgboost: 0.4.0.c4fa2f-py35_0 local
(root) ~/condaexpts $ python -c 'import xgboost; print(xgboost.__version__)'
0.4
```